# How to bind observableArray by index to the element

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I've been developing a web application that will display a table containing list of candidates. I want to display the candidate collection (get from the server) to the table, but with fixed row count to display, let's say 5 rows. So if the collection only have 2 candidates, the table will be having 5 rows, with the only first 2 rows contains the data, and the remaining 3 are empty rows.

I couldn't use the foreach binding to solve this, so I tried [this post](http://jsfiddle.net/tyrsius/GB4ae/).

In that post the objects inside observableArray are not observable, so I tried to make them observable and it still works. But when I try in my code, it throws error in my js:

```
Unable to process binding "text: function (){return Candidates[0]().CandidateNumber }"
Message: AssignedCandidates[0] is not a function
```

I'm still not sure what I'm missing. Please help.

This is my js file:

```
var CandidateViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    self.CandidateId = ko.observable();
    self.CandidateNumber = ko.observable();
    self.Name = ko.observable();
    self.Status = ko.observable()
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
}

var mappingCandidateList = {
    Candidates: {
        create: function (options) {
            return new CandidateViewModel(options.data);
        }
    }
}

var CandidateListViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    self.Candidates = ko.observableArray();
    self.AssignedCount = ko.observable();
    self.ProcessingCount = ko.observable();
    self.RejectingCount = ko.observable();
    self.PassedCount = ko.observable();
    self.FailedCount = ko.observable();
    self.PagingInfo = ko.observable();

    var getData = function (param) {
        $.ajax({
            url: api("Candidate/GetCandidates"),
            data: param,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'JSON'
        }).done(function (data) {
            ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mappingCandidateList, self);
        });
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new CandidateListViewModel (), document.getElementById('candidate-container'));
```

and this is the html

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>number</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: Candidates()[0].CandidateNumber"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: Candidates()[0].Name"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: Candidates()[0].Status"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: At the surface it seems like instead of `Candidates[0]().CandidateNumber`, it should be `Candidates()[0].CandidateNumber`. But it would be helpful if you could post a snippet or [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Thanks @NisargShah , I've created a workaround for that using with data-bind `<tr data-bind="with: Candidates()[0]">` but it still not generating the DOM if there is no data at the index. And I can't produce the error, I tried in the new code environment `<td data-bind="text: Candidates()[0].Name"></td>` is work well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can* use the `foreach` binding to get your guaranteed 5 rows, you'll just need a computed property that ensures the exact length of 5.

For example:

- Define fixed number of rows (`NR_OF_ROWS`)
- Create a `pureComputed` and bind to it using `foreach`
- Make the `pureComputed` return an array of length `NR_OF_ROWS`
- Loop over this array and inject a `candidate` for every index that has one available
- If there are no more candidates, inject an empty candidate that tells your view what to render.

```js
var VM = function() {
  const NR_OF_ROWS = 5;

  this.candidates = ko.observableArray([
    { id: 1, firstName: "Jane", lastName: "Doe" },
    { id: 2, firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe" }
  ]);
  
  this.displayRows = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    const emptyCandidate = { id: "-", firstName: "-", lastName: "-", empty: true };
    const candidates = this.candidates();
    const rows = [];
    
    for (let i = 0; i < NR_OF_ROWS; i += 1) {
      rows.push(candidates[i] || emptyCandidate);
    }
    
    return rows;
  }, this);
  
  // For demo
  this.newCandidate = {
    firstName: ko.observable(""),
    lastName: ko.observable(""),
    add: function() {
      this.candidates.push({ 
        firstName: this.newCandidate.firstName(), 
        lastName: this.newCandidate.lastName(), 
        id: this.candidates().length + 1 
      })
    }.bind(this)
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```

```css
tr:nth-child(even) { background: #efefef; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: displayRows">
    <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: firstName"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: lastName"></td>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div data-bind="with: newCandidate">
  <input type="text" placeholder="first name" data-bind="textInput: firstName">
  <input type="text" placeholder="last name" data-bind="textInput: lastName">
  <button data-bind="click: add">add</button>
</div>
```

---

**Edit:** if you'd rather have a special view for an empty row, rather than a special viewmodel, you can use templates:

```js
var VM = function() {
  const NR_OF_ROWS = 5;

  this.candidates = ko.observableArray([
    { id: 1, firstName: "Jane", lastName: "Doe" },
    { id: 2, firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe" }
  ]);
  
  this.displayRows = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    const candidates = this.candidates();
    const rows = [];
    
    for (let i = 0; i < NR_OF_ROWS; i += 1) {
      rows.push(candidates[i] || emptyCandidate);
    }
    
    return rows;
  }, this);
  
  // For demo
  this.newCandidate = {
    firstName: ko.observable(""),
    lastName: ko.observable(""),
    add: function() {
      this.candidates.push({ 
        firstName: this.newCandidate.firstName(), 
        lastName: this.newCandidate.lastName(), 
        id: this.candidates().length + 1 
      })
    }.bind(this)
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```

```css
tr:nth-child(even) { background: #efefef; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: displayRows">
    <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: firstName"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: lastName"></td>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div data-bind="with: newCandidate">
  <input type="text" placeholder="first name" data-bind="textInput: firstName">
  <input type="text" placeholder="last name" data-bind="textInput: lastName">
  <button data-bind="click: add">add</button>
</div>
```

Comment: That worked. But I need to code another object for the empty one, which will be a lot of work when the properties of the viewModel are so many. I'll try to find a workaround for this. Anyway thanks @user3297291

Comment: You can also push `null` to the array, but you'll need to update your view. For example: `<!-- ko if: $data --> regular row <!-- /ko --> <!-- ko ifnot: $data --> an empty row <!-- /ko -->`. My advice would be to use two templates.

Comment: I've added an example that shows you how you can use the `template: { foreach }` binding to circumvent having to create empty viewmodels.

Comment: I prefer to avoid virtual elements on the view. And about the empty row, it crashed when I insert the empty object to the displayRow array. Instead I insert new viewModel to the displayRow array and that worked well, until there are some buttons to add in the row, the buttons are rendered too in the empty row haha